# Isoperimetric constant of a product of regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a locally finite infinite regular random graph. Define the Cheeger constant as: $\Phi:=\inf \frac{|\partial S|}{|S|}$. I've been wondering how $\Phi$ behaves wrt the cartesian product of graphs. In other words, is it true that $\Phi_{G_1\times G_2}=\Phi_{G_1}+\Phi_{G_2}$?

My attempt:
On the one hand proving $\le $ is trivial, but $\ge$ seems to be harder. It is possible to prove the result using the edge expansion duality (see "Probability on Trees and Networks", Lyon&Peres, thm 6.1), but feels to me like killing a fly with a nuke.

Is there an easier approach to the $\ge$ part of the result?